# How to show a continuous markov chain is irreducible?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, monte-carlo

> Are the Markov Chains associated with the below equations **invariant** and **irreducible**?

> 1. PMF $f = (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)$ and kernel
>    $$K = \begin{bmatrix} 
>    1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
>    1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
>    0 & 0 & 1
>    \end{bmatrix}$$

> 2. PDF $g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$ and $K(x,y) = g(y)$

> 3. PDF $h(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$ and $\int_A K(x,y)dy=1_A(x)$, for $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and initial value $x$.

1. $f*K = K$ hence invariant. No other state can be reached from {3}, therefore not irreducible.
2. $g*K = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-1/2(x^2+y^2)} \neq K,$ so not invariant. For any $t>0$, then $K^t > 0$, so the integral is non-negative and hence irreducible.
3. If $\int K = 1_A$, then $K=0$? So, $h*K=0 \neq K$, so not invariant. Since $\int K = 1_A$, then $\int K^t >0$ , hence irreducible.

**SOLUTION:**

*1: invariant, not irreducible.
2: invariant, irreducible.
3: invariant, not irreducible.*

Where did i go wrong for 2 and 3?

Irreducibility for continuous MCs are defined as:

Given a distribution, $\mu$, over $E$, a MC is irreducible if for all points $x \in E$ and all measurable sets $A$ such that $\mu(A) > 0$ there exists some $t$
such that:

$$ \int_A K^t(x,y) dy > 0$$

Comment: Irreducibility is defined in the continuous context how, exactly?

Comment: @FShrike hmmm is it if $K^t > 0$ for $t>0$?

Comment: You misunderstand. This is your question so you should already have a definition of irreducibility in order to answer this question - I’m just asking what definition you’re expected to use because I’ve never seen this in a continuous context.

Comment: But you did the convolution incorrectly

Comment: @FShrike I have added the definition now, i guess it's correct now? May i ask why $g*K$ is incorrect though?

Comment: What is $K^t$? And why does it have two inputs

Comment: Your kernel in $K$ confuses me as it doesn’t appear to be a function of both $(x,y)$, please clarify.

Comment: *I meant “ your kernel in 2)”

Comment: OK edited the question, it is a function of two inputs, but don't think it changes my calculations. Also, $K^t$ is from the definition of irreducibility

Comment: The answer to 3), according to you, agrees with your answer. The answer to 2), according to you, disagrees with you only on the point that it should be invariant. You also still haven’t defined $K^t$, and when I looked up “continuous Markov chain” I get stuff about rate matrices, etc, not stuff to do with probability density functions and convolution, so I cannot guess what you mean.

Comment: Sorry 3 is wrong. For irreducibility i need to show that for some $t$, $\int K^t dy >0$. Therefore if $K^t >0$, then it should be irreducible according to the definition right? I don't need to give a definition of $K^t$. Essentially, irreducibility in continuous space is what class of states are reachable from one another and hence what part of E might be explored, with positive probability, starting from a point within such a class.

Comment: .... you want help with 3). The answer says it is not irreducible and you say it is. In order for someone else to resolve that for you, **they need to know what $K^t$** means. Unless you want to wait for potentially a very long time for someone who knows your notation to come along, you may as well write a clear question and define $K^t$. I have only been trying to help you here!

Comment: @FShrike I know, but there is no definition of $K^t$ that i have so i'm not sure what to provide, as i only have a definition of $K$, the theorem just asks that if $\int K^t >0$, then it's irreducible, where $t$ is for example time of the Markov Chain.